# C++ Linear search returning just 0

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-search

So I am a newbie in C++, I do code in JS, for some reason I can't figure out the mistake here, please help me out. thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int search(char input, char sentence[]){
    for(int i = 2; i != '\0'; i++){
        if(sentence[i] == input){
            return i;        

        }else{ return -1; }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char key[20] = "hey my name is sid!";
    char ser = 'm';
   cout << search(ser,key);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `i != '\0'` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition in the for loop is wrong, you are not checking the string only the index. Also if your character did not match, you do not want to exit immediately.

The correct code would be:

```
for(int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if(sentence[i] == input)
    {
        return i;        
    }
}
return -1;
```

If you want to start the search at the third character you should first ensure that your string has at least three elements:

```
if(strlen(sentence)>=3)
{
    for(int i = 2; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: maybe the op wants to start checking the sentence at the 3rd element...

Answer (score 3):

For your search function, you are only really checking the first character in the loop, then returning.  You should move "return -1;" outside of the for loop as then it will only be called after the entire string was checked for the value and it was not found.

```
int search(char input, char sentence[]) {
    for (int i = 2; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (sentence[i] == input) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

in addition to changing the conditions of the for loop as other users mentioned.